# Converting timestamp string with T and Z characters to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I don't know how to convert this string to NSDate.

Date is in this format "2012-10-21T07:00:00Z"

I guess the problem is that I have no clue what those T and Z mean in the string :)

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *dateStart = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-10-21T07:00:00Z"];

// format that I want
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSLog(@"date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:dateStart]);
```

all dates are in that format: `2014-09-12T03:46:25Z`

Comment: Compare your date string to the format string.  How are they similar?  How are they different?  Have you looked at [the spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)?

Comment: This is the second most-common iOS question here (after "unrecognized selector").

Comment: @HotLicks, "passing data/object/array to view controller" is even more often, I'd say.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - Yeah, how did I forget about that???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an ISO date. The Z stands for Zulu but means UTC time.

Try:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

To feed your initial nsdate.

Comment: Actually, based on that single sample it's not clear whether the format should end with ZZZZZ or just Z.  One would need to know how the timezone is expressed when it's not UTC.

Comment: (The thing that fixed it was putting `T` in single quotes.)

Comment: Also consider setting the locale as suggested in [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).